# EAV, сложность выборки (фильтрации)

Tags: mysql

В базе данных значения параметров объявлений хранятся в отдельной таблице. Один параметр - одна запись, с привязякой к объявлению и типу параметра.

Проблемы начались при попытке отфильтровать.
Вот таблица:

```
id - уникальный порядковый номер в таблице
id_ads: - к какому объявлению привязано
p_id: группа параметров
value: значение параметра

{id:1, id_ads: "1", p_id: "1", value: "5"}
{id:2, id_ads: "1", p_id: "2", value: "1"}
{id:3, id_ads: "1", p_id: "3", value: "6"}
{id:4, id_ads: "1", p_id: "4", value: "11"}

{id:5, id_ads: "2", p_id: "1", value: "5"}
{id:6, id_ads: "2", p_id: "2", value: "4"}
{id:7, id_ads: "2", p_id: "3", value: "8"}
{id:8, id_ads: "2", p_id: "7", value: "8"}
{id:9, id_ads: "2", p_id: "7", value: "2"}

{id:10, id_ads: "3", p_id: "1", value: "5"}
{id:11, id_ads: "3", p_id: "2", value: "1"}
{id:12, id_ads: "3", p_id: "3", value: "8"}
{id:13, id_ads: "3", p_id: "6", value: "1"}
```

Запрос такой: Нужно показать номера объявления, которые имеют 
(p_id = 1 AND value = 5)
(p_id = 2 AND value = 1)

одновременно

Под такие условия подпадает записи:

```
{id:1, id_ads: "1", p_id: "1", value: "5"}
{id:2, id_ads: "1", p_id: "2", value: "1"}

{id:5, id_ads: "2", p_id: "1", value: "5"}

{id:10, id_ads: "3", p_id: "1", value: "5"}
{id:11, id_ads: "3", p_id: "2", value: "1"}
```

Но так как одновременно они есть только у объявлений id_ads = 1 и id_ads = 3
то результатом должно быть: 1,3

Объявление № 2 (id_ads = 2) не подходит так как не содержит второго необходимого параметра.

Как я только не пытался, решить вопрос не смог.
Буду надеется что кто-то знает решение.

**Альтернативное решение # 1**
получить эти 5 строк из базы, прогнать массивом php и увидеть что по одному из обьявлений 1 строка вместо двух (два условия), и удалить её.

Но это какой-то костыль.

**Альтернативное решение # 2**
Циклические запросы.
1. WHERE p_id = 1 AND value = 5
   получаем массив id_ads: 1,2,3

2. WHERE p_id = 2 AND value = 1 AND id_ads IN (1,2,3)
   получаем (1,3).

   Соотсветственно если пункта 2 зациклить на количество видов фильтров
   уменьшая конечный массив id_ads до нужного результата

   Но опять костыль.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id_ads
FROM datatable
WHERE (p_id, value) IN ((1,5), (2,1)) -- 2 пары значений, но можно больше
GROUP BY id_ads
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p_id, value) = 2 -- столько, сколько пар значений
```

Если (p_id, value) уникально (не логика приложения, а именно уникальный/первичный индекс) - DISTINCT можно убрать.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо. Работает.

Comment: Так же работает в таком представлении: WHERE p_id IN (1,2) AND value IN (5,1)   - то есть в таком представлении в скобках не пара параметр-значение, а перечисление вначале параметров, потом значений.  В любом случае Ваше решение и есть ответ.

Comment: *Так же работает в таком представлении: WHERE p_id IN (1,2) AND value IN (5,1)* Только неправильно. Создай пару записей с комбинациями (1,1) и (2,5) - убедишься. А так - да, работает...

Answer (score 0):

Если я верно понял тебе нужно сделать выборку из выборки, можно так:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `table`
 WHERE
      p_id = 1 
      AND 
      value = 5
      AND
id_ads IN (SELECT id_ads
                   FROM `delete`
                  WHERE 
          p_id = 2 
          AND 
          value = 1)
```

Comment: Да, логика верная.

Comment: Логика верная. Но количество таких вложений может достигать 10 или 20. То есть, пользователь выбирает фильтры, и это массив (фильтров) приходит в обработчик и тут начинается построение запроса. Для двух чекбоксов Ваш пример подойдет. А если выбрано 20 фильтров? То есть во вложении будут вложения, а внутри ещё вложениния SELECT IN.  По скорости обработки пока быстрее получается выбрать SELECT FROM WHERE (p_id =2 AND value =1) OR (p_id = 1 AND value = 5) и всё. Получится таблица, которую мы прогоним через php функцию, где оставим только те id, количество которых совпадает с количеством фильтров.

Comment: Понял, не знал что выборок из бд может бть больше двух, как по мне разумнее всего средством php сортировать. Ибо при таком количестве вложеных запросов, нагрузка на бд будет великой. Особенно если онлайн частый.